# Exchange 2010 problem with one user not being able to send as other

Tags: exchange-2010

I've user which was given full access to another account called info. This user can see all emails in outlook since Info is attached as 2nd mailbox for that user. Problem is that mails sent from that account by user are never delivered and nothing is returned (no error msg etc). User have full access to that Info mailbox and same settings seems to work for everyone else.

Got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could verify that it is configured correctly: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676368.aspx

Alternatively, you can enable message tracing: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997984.aspx and figure out where/why its not working.

Comment: Hrmms.. i've now checked and Send As was missing. When i checked it last time i could sware it was there.

Comment: Could the AdminSDHolder issue from Exchange 2003\2007 be causing this? I know Exchange 2010 uses a new authorization layer (RBAC) so I don't know if this would cause your issue or not.